# Python Lambda function usage

Tags: python, lambda, keras, loss-function

I have come across this line of code.

```
loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}
```

**1. What is the function of lambda here?**

**2. What is the use of 'ctc' here?**

Comment: Is this a loss reference?

Comment: About the "ctc", it's probably recovered somewhere else in the code, such as `loss['ctc']` or `loss['ctc'](arg1,arg2)`.

Answer (score 5):

The lambda function return the second parameter: y_pred
It's simply like this function:

```
def foo(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred
```

The use of 'ctc' is as a key in the dictionary `loss`:

```
loss['ctc'] = lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred
```

For example I can do:

```
loss['ctc'](0, 1)
```

And this will return 1

Answer (score 2):

here lambda itself function,

```
lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred
```

coresponding function,

```
def something(y_true, y_pred):
   return y_pred
```

**y_true, y_pred** both are aruguments passing into function,

**y_pred** return value which is stored into key 'ctc'

Answer (score 1):

```
lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred
```

can be expanded as:

```
def foo(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred  
# function takes two parameters, returns second parameter.
```

**Notes on lambda**:

- The lambda operator or lambda function is a way to create small
  anonymous functions.
- Lambda functions are throw-away functions, i.e. they are just needed where they have been created.

`ctc` is a key in the dictionary `loss`.

```
loss = {'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}
```

can otherwise be written as,

```
loss['ctc'] = lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred
```

Comment: Not the returned item, it's storing the function itself to be called from the dictionary.